# How can i save the Detail List for each item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

i'm using Android Studio to make an application that manage my sales, i'v use a list of sales, if we click at some sale this will navigate us to the sale it self(Another activity).

In the sale detail acivity i'm using a button that adds texts we write.

For example: Writing the text "1 blue castro Tshirt" in the edit text and click add 5 times will make a list with 5 lines of this string.

The problem is saving details for each sale.

How can i make it save details for each sale so i can restart the application and find every sale with its details?

Java Code for Detail Sale activity:

```
import...

public class ItemDetailActivity extends ListActivity {


private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    final OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.add(edit.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




}   
};



    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Java Code for item list (Sales list) activity:

```
package com.galilsoftware.myapplication;

import...

public class ItemListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Button AddCust;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
    AddCust = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddCust);


    AddCust.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    }
);

    View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);

    if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {

        mTwoPane = true;
    }
}

private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items)     {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
}
```

XML for Sale Detail:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/hintTxtItem"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lblBtnAdd"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItem"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
        android:text="@string/txtEmpty"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML for Sales List:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.galilsoftware.a415hgufhdcgh.ItemListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <Button
            android:text="הוספת לקוח"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AddCust"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
    </FrameLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use SQLite database to store all items and their details. You may also want to save the data to a remote server to be persistent after the app gets uninstalled

Answer (score 1):

you can use Sqlite database or Shared preference to save details of sale. So that you can retrieve data from shared preference or Sqlite database for later use. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model class for storing the information of details and make it Parceable like this:

```
public class Sale implements Parcelable{
String name;
String details;

protected Sale(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    details = in.readString();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public static final Creator<Sale> CREATOR = new Creator<Sale>() {
    @Override
    public Sale createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Sale(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Sale[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Sale[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(details);
}
```

}

Now,you can store and retrieve this ArrayList in Shared Preferences using GSON which can be added in gradle like below:

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
```

To store ArrayList in preferences:

```
ArrayList<Sale> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Add your sale and their details here..
Save it just as string to the preference.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list);
Utils.storeUserPreferences(context,"LIST",json);
```

To retrieve this ArrayList,
First retrive as string from preference then convert it to List with help of Gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = Utils.getUserPreferences(context,"LIST");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Sale>>(){}.getType();
final List<Sale> list=gson.fromJson(json, type);
```